# VBA for performing action until cell meets criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I've had no luck on searching this, I hope you all can help.

I am trying to perform the following in Excel:

If a cell matches a value from table1, highlight that cell. Then highlight the cell below it and continue to highlight the cells below it until it reaches a cell that matches a value from table2.

I cant figure out how to work in the loop function for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with a specific example.

Comment: Look at the `Do Loop` examples [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple for loop, which iterates through the data range. My data table consists of integers 1 - 15, named 'Data'. The starting point is named 'Point_1' and the ending point is named 'Point_2'.

The code is below, annotated for clarity. In essence, it is simply toggling highlight ON when the cell matches Point_1, and highlighting until it is toggled back OFF, when the cell matches Point_2.

```
Sub HighlightRange()
Dim cel As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim highlighting As Boolean

highlighting = False

With Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set dataRange = .Range("Data") 'This is your data range. I named mine 'Data'

    For Each cel In dataRange
        'Check for beginning or end values
        If cel = .Range("Point_1").Value Then 'This is your starting value. I named mine 'Point_1'
            highlighting = True
        ElseIf cel = .Range("Point_2").Value Then 'This is your ending value. I named mine 'Point_2'
            highlighting = False
        End If

        'While highlighting is activated, highlight the current cell
        If highlighting = True Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If

    Next cel 'Check all cells in dataRange

End With

End Sub
```

Notably, the end point is not highlighted. However, you can move the ElseIf statement that turns highlighting back off to the end of the for loop, after the highlight command. This will turn highlighting off AFTER highlighting Point_2 instead of just before. Code for this case is below.

```
Sub HighlightRange()
Dim cel As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim highlighting As Boolean

highlighting = False

With Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'This code also highlights Point_2.

    Set dataRange = .Range("Data") 'This is your data range. I named mine 'Data'

    For Each cel In dataRange
        'Check for beginning or end values
        If cel = .Range("Point_1").Value Then 'This is your starting value. I named mine 'Point_1'
            highlighting = True
        End If

        'While highlighting is activated, highlight the current cell
        If highlighting = True Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If

        If cel = .Range("Point_2").Value Then 'This is your ending value. I named mine 'Point_2'
            highlighting = False
        End If

    Next cel 'Check all cells in dataRange

End With

End Sub
```

I hope this helped! You can change the highlight color from blue (colorIndex = 5) to whatever color you like. If you click Record Macro and format a cell just how you want, you can copy the generated code into this macro in place of the following line:

```
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

Cheers and Good Luck!